# $watch doesn't fire when object property is set to a function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

It seems that when changing an object property, watches on that object fires - unless the property is set to a function.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.object1 = {};
    $scope.object2 = {};

    $scope.clicked1 = function() {
        $scope.object1.message = "Object1 property changed"            
    }

    $scope.clicked2 = function() {
        $scope.object1.fn = function() {
            return "Object1 fn changed";
        }
    }

    $scope.$watch('object1', function(o) {
        if (o.message)
            $scope.object2.message = o.message + ', and watch fired';
        else if (o.fn) {
            $scope.object2.message = o.fn();
        }
    }, true);
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/TkWP6/. When clicked1 is called, the $watch fires as expected, but when clicked2 is called, nothing happens.

The simple question is why not, and can anything be done to get the $watch to fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass true as the last parameter, Angular uses its object equality function to compare the past and present states of the object:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.equals

> During a property comparision, properties of function type and
>   properties with names that begin with $ are ignored.

I think if you want the watch to trigger, you're going to have to change an additional property at the same time you modify the functional property.